# null pointer exception on jython exec import

Tags: java, python, jython

I am using a jython script in my java project, but the java class shows null pointer error while importing jython script.

[image]

the error is in Chat.java

Chat.java 
package pack;

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.python.util.PythonInterpreter;
import org.python.core.*;
..............................
@Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        System.out.println("inside servlet");
        String chattext= request.getParameter("cahttext");
        PythonInterpreter pi = null;
        try{
                Properties p = new Properties();
                p.setProperty("python.path", "PATH OF JYTHON");
                p.setProperty("python.home", "PATH OF JYTHON");
                p.setProperty("python.prefix", "PATH OF JYTHON");
                PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), p, new String[] {});
                pi = new PythonInterpreter();
        }catch(Exception e){}
        try{
            pi.exec("from chatmodule import chat");              //error here(line 56)
            pi.set("chattext", new PyString(chattext));
            pi.exec("out = chat(chattext)");
            pi.exec("print(out)");
            String out=pi.get("out").toString();
            System.out.println("out = "+out);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("this exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

stack trace

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at pack.Chat.doPost(Chat.java:56)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:240)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:207)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:212)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:94)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:496)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:141)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:620)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:502)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1156)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:684)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1539)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1495)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I assume that the problem is, java does not find the jython file. So I tried putting it in different places as you can see in the project structure. Still it is not working. I have not imported the jython script, because I didn't find anything in the tutorials. I am new to Java and jython. So please somebody help me with this.

Thank you

Comment: i guess there is exception in first try block that you have ignored. there is no need of two try block, you can manage this code in one try block.

Comment: Is `chatmodule.py` in the root folder of your .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

Change method like below, only one try/catch is enough for this, you will exact exception.

```
 protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    System.out.println("inside servlet");
    String chattext= request.getParameter("cahttext");
    PythonInterpreter pi = null;
    try{
        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.setProperty("python.path", "PATH OF JYTHON");
        p.setProperty("python.home", "PATH OF JYTHON");
        p.setProperty("python.prefix", "PATH OF JYTHON");
        PythonInterpreter.initialize(System.getProperties(), p, new String[] {});
        pi = new PythonInterpreter();

        pi.exec("from chatmodule import chat");              //error here(line 56)
        pi.set("chattext", new PyString(chattext));
        pi.exec("out = chat(chattext)");
        pi.exec("print(out)");
        String out=pi.get("out").toString();
        System.out.println("out = "+out);
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("this exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```